# Paypal REST SDK creates payment request but instantly closes Paypal window

Tags: javascript, php, rest, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have followed the Paypal guide seen here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/payments/ in PHP and although I have seemingly gotten that part of the process to work the client side javascript doesn't seem to work properly.

The payment function below([Source here](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server)):

```
payment: function() {

            // Set up a url on your server to create the payment
            var CREATE_URL = '/demo/checkout/api/paypal/payment/create/';

            // Make a call to your server to set up the payment
            return paypal.request.post(CREATE_URL)
                .then(function(res) {
                    return res.paymentID;
                });
        },
```

Makes the call to my payment creation page, which does properly spit out a sandbox.paypal.com/etc. page but the Paypal window on the client facing page immediately closes without any kind of error.

If I manually go to my payment creation page, grab that url and go there myself I can log in, make my test payment and get forwarded to the ending confirmation page so I know the link itself is good, I just don't know why the javascript fails and closes the window.